# Open the editor with text from parameter

Tags: sublimetext3

I was wondering either it is possible in sublime text to open the program with some text pasted in already. For example something like:

```
sublime_text3 --someFlag "Text to be in the editor"
```

And after executing this command new sublime text window opens with the text from the quote. Is that possible? I would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ST supports "commands" to be specified on the command line. In ST, the command to create a new tab is `new_file` and the command to insert text is `insert`, as can be seen from the Default keybindings file.

Therefore, you can achieve what you want with:

```
subl --command new_file --command "insert {\"characters\": \"Text to be in the editor\"}"
```

(Tested on Windows Command Prompt and Linux Bash.)

I wrote a bit more about using commands from the commandline in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44566357/4473405

(There is currently no way to do this without using commands/by using stdin, as reported at https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1236)

Answer (score -1):

In Bash, you can use [here strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) to pass standard input a command:

> A here string can be considered as a stripped-down form of a here document.
> It consists of nothing more than COMMAND <<< $WORD,
> where $WORD is expanded and fed to the stdin of COMMAND.

**Example:**

`subl <<< "Text to be in the editor"`

Alternatively, you can use the following:

`"Text to be in the editor" | subl`

Comment: This doesnt really work, I think a specific program has to be written the way he can obtain this kind of pass.

Comment: Probably depends on your version of Bash, it works fine in v3.2

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` When I use it sublime text opens like with no argument.